# Flutter Scrollable Stack with Height greater than Screen Height

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a widget hierarchy where `SingleChildScrollView` is the parent with a `Stack` as the child, the `Stack` has two children, if the Second child goes beyond the screen height its height gets clipped. According to docs the stack occupies size according to a `Non-Positioned` child. So that means we have to explicitly give a height to the `Stack`, but this height is arbitrary and it won't wrap the contents inside. My main aim is to wrap the `SingleChildScrollView` height rather than having empty space at bottom.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height + 150,
      child: SafeArea(
        bottom: false,
        child: Stack(
           fit: StackFit.expand,
          children: <Widget>[
              Container(height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .35,),
              Positioned(top: top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .35 +
                  MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.top,..)
                 ...]))))
```

[![image][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnoP0.png[image]

Comment: Why not using ``Expanded`` widget ?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: The Empty space should not be there, the space that i have highlighted with a black box

Comment: the second positioned container has content beyond the screen height,i am giving an arbitary height to stacks parent in order to make content visilbe beyond screen height, but this height is the issue, it is arbitrary. The question is how to give a constrainted  height  that works on all screens or if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the final output? How you want it to look like?

Comment: What type of layout are you trying to achieve can you share the screenshot? May be there will be no need to include stack, or we can provide you with more better way to do this.

Comment: Ok, i have added the layout that i want to achieve , the main things to keep in consideration is the that layout is scrollable , the top right and left curve in the white card and the background image on top portion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had finally achieved it by Translating the bottom section along y axis by -20.0 units, that way it overlapped the top section. Which i think was the only way to achieve this for the particular scenario. For other good solutions in other scenarios check @copsOnRoad's fantastic writeup below

```
    Transform.translate(
offset: Offset(0.0, -20.0),
  child: Container(
    height: 100.0,
    width: 100.0,
    color: Colors.yellow,
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 27):

### Solution #1

[image]

Do let me know if this isn't what you were looking for.

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: HomePage()));

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 44, left: 24, right: 24, bottom: 20),
            color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                      onPressed: () {},
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Spacer(),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                      onPressed: () {},
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(color: Colors.white, width: 100, height: 100),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          _myText("Your name", 16),
                          _myText("24 years old", 14),
                          SizedBox(height: 6),
                          _myText("Martial status", 16),
                          _myText("Unmarried", 14),
                          SizedBox(height: 6),
                          Container(padding: EdgeInsets.all(4), color: Colors.blue, child: _myText("PLUS PLAN - 1 DAY LEFT", 12)),
                          SizedBox(height: 12),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: double.maxFinite,
                  child: OutlineButton(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 2),
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: _myText("CHANGE PLAN", 16),
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  "Higher plans give you more connects",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: Colors.white70),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                _buildCard1(),
                _buildCard(size: 70, color: Colors.deepOrange),
                _buildCard(size: 80, color: Colors.purple),
                _buildCard(size: 90, color: Colors.pink),
                _buildCard(size: 100, color: Colors.grey),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _myText(String data, double size) => Text(data, style: TextStyle(fontSize: size, color: Colors.white));

  Widget _buildCard1() {
    return Card(
      elevation: 4,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(12),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text("PROFILE DETAILS"),
          ),
          Placeholder(fallbackHeight: 200),
          Divider(),
          SizedBox(
            width: double.maxFinite,
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text("UPDATE MY PROFILE"),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildCard({double size, Color color}) {
    return Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(12),
      child: Container(height: size, color: color,),
    );
  }
}
```

---

### Solution # 2

[image]

Is this what you were looking for? (Here I only modified above `build()` method, rest of the method remains same.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
    body: SafeArea(
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12, left: 24, right: 24, bottom: 20),
            color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                      onPressed: () {},
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Spacer(),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                      onPressed: () {},
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(color: Colors.white, width: 100, height: 100),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          _myText("Your name", 16),
                          _myText("24 years old", 14),
                          SizedBox(height: 6),
                          _myText("Martial status", 16),
                          _myText("Unmarried", 14),
                          SizedBox(height: 6),
                          Container(padding: EdgeInsets.all(4), color: Colors.blue, child: _myText("PLUS PLAN - 1 DAY LEFT", 12)),
                          SizedBox(height: 12),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: double.maxFinite,
                  child: OutlineButton(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 2),
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: _myText("CHANGE PLAN", 16),
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  "Higher plans give you more connects",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: Colors.white70),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal(left: Radius.circular(30), right: Radius.circular(30))
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                _buildCard1(),
                _buildCard(size: 70, color: Colors.deepOrange),
                _buildCard(size: 80, color: Colors.purple),
                _buildCard(size: 90, color: Colors.pink),
                _buildCard(size: 100, color: Colors.grey),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

---

### Solution #3

[image]

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: SafeArea(
      child: DecoratedBox(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage("your_image_here"), fit: BoxFit.cover)),
        child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              expandedHeight: 300,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                collapseMode: CollapseMode.pin,
                background: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage("your_image_here"), fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12, left: 24, right: 24, bottom: 20),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                            onPressed: () {},
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          Spacer(),
                          IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                            onPressed: () {},
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(color: Colors.white, width: 100, height: 100),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                _myText("Your name", 16),
                                _myText("24 years old", 14),
                                SizedBox(height: 6),
                                _myText("Martial status", 16),
                                _myText("Unmarried", 14),
                                SizedBox(height: 6),
                                Container(padding: EdgeInsets.all(4), color: Colors.blue, child: _myText("PLUS PLAN - 1 DAY LEFT", 12)),
                                SizedBox(height: 12),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: double.maxFinite,
                        child: OutlineButton(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 2),
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: _myText("CHANGE PLAN", 16),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Higher plans give you more connects",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: Colors.white70),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                [
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.orange,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal(
                          left: Radius.circular(30),
                          right: Radius.circular(30),
                        )),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        _buildCard1(),
                        _buildCard(size: 100, color: Colors.deepOrange),
                        _buildCard(size: 80, color: Colors.purple),
                        _buildCard(size: 100, color: Colors.pink),
                        _buildCard(size: 180, color: Colors.grey),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks @copsonroad Well explained.