# How to initialize state using the Provider package?

Tags: dart, flutter, state-management

```
TL;DR - Getting providerInfo = null from Consumer<ProviderInfo>(
    builder: (context, providerInfo, child),
```

I have a flutter app that uses [scoped_model](https://pub.dev/packages/scoped_model) that works just fine but I want to refactor it so it'll use [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)

**The code with scoped_model:**

```
//imports...
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final MainModel _model = MainModel();// The data class, extends scoped_model.Model class, with all of other models...
  bool _isAuthenticated = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _model.init();
    super.initState();
}
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScopedModel<MainModel>(
      model: _model,
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: "MyApp",
        routes: {
          '/': (BuildContext context) => _isAuthenticated == false ? AuthenticationPage() : HomePage(_model),
          '/admin': (BuildContext context) =>
              _isAuthenticated == false ? AuthenticationPage() : AdminPage(_model),
        },
// the rest of build...

}
```

**and the code that I tried to refactor to use Provider:**

```
//@lib/main.dart
//imports...
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<ProviderInfo>(
      builder: (context) {
        ProviderInfo(); // the data model. 
      },
      child: Consumer<ProviderInfo>(
        builder: (context, providerInfo, child) => MaterialApp(
              title: "MyApp",
              routes: {
                '/': (BuildContext context) {
                  providerInfo.isAuthenticated == false ? AuthenticationPage() : HomePage(providerInfo);
                },
                '/admin': (BuildContext context) {
                    providerInfo.isAuthenticated == false ? AuthenticationPage() : AdminPage(_model);
                },     
//the rest of build...
              },

//@ProviderInfo
class ProviderInfo extends CombinedModel with ProductModel, UserModel, UtilityModel {

  ProviderInfo() {
    this.init();
  }
}
```

The problem with this code is that in the builder function of `Consumer<ProviderInfo>` the `providerInfo` is null (and also after of course, in routes etc...).

what did I do wrong? 
how can I refactor it so it'll works fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to return something in the `builder` of your provider.

Change

```
 ProviderInfo()
```

To

```
 return ProviderInfo()
```

Comment: You attention is much https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56204912/flutter-scrollable-stack-with-height-greater-than-screen-height